# Filter a tibble by summarize data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble with lots of values. I know that some of the values are "bad", because they are overrepresented in the data.

What I'd like to do is filter out any value that occurs more than, say, 10 times.

I can easily get the count of occurrences by doing

```
values %>% group_by(value) %>% summarize(count=n())

# A tibble: 1,000 x 2
       value count
     <dbl> <int>
 1 1.40e15     1
 2 1.40e15     2
 3 1.40e15     1
 4 1.40e15    17
 5 1.40e15     2
 6 1.40e15     7
 7 1.40e15     1
```

But how do I now filter the original `values` tibble to remove any value that occurs more than 10 times in the summary?

Comment: `values %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(n()<=10) %>% ungroup()`